# How can I pass an argument to onCancel from {...bind} using useLongPress.js in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some code like this in React. I'd like to intercept the *single click* and *tap*, and the *long click* e *long press* so I used [useLongPress.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-long-press).

So, I thought to remove `onClick={() => start(preset)}` from the button and call `start(preset)` from `shortPress` function. But how can I pass the `preset` argument as well?

```
const Presets = ({presetsList: presets, presetStart: start}) => {
    
    const longPress = () => {
          console.log('long click or long press');
          // Some other code... 
    }

    const shortPress = event => {
        console.log('single click or tap')
       // start(preset)
    }
    
    const bind = useLongPress(longPress, {onCancel: shortPress} )
      
    return (
        <section onContextMenu={(e)=> e.preventDefault()}>
            {presets.map( preset => {
                return <button 
                            key={presets.indexOf(preset)} 
                            onClick={() => start(preset)} 
                            {...bind} 
                            type="button" 
                        >
                            <span>{preset.time}</span>
                        </button>
            })}
        </section>
    )
}
 
export default Presets;
```

Basically, I'd need to pass an argument to `onCancel` callback from `{...bind}`. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

```js
{presets.map(preset => {
  const bind = useLongPress(longPress, { onCancel: shortPress.bind(null, preset) })
  return (
    <button 
      key={presets.indexOf(preset)} 
      onClick={() => start(preset)} 
      type="button" 
      {...bind}
    >
      <span>{preset.time}</span>
    </button>
})}
```

**Please read:**

If you take a look in the code of that hook library, the hook is returning a bunch of event handlers for you to spread on your element. And it relies on these event handlers to know when the long press happens or stops, etc.

For a few of these event listeners and handlers, a callback will be called that performs some logic and conditionally runs the function you provide as `onCancel` for you to do your own logic.

Unfortunately, the package you mentioned does not return the actual `cancel` function for you to use, but what it does return is an object that has the `cancel` function as the value of some of its properties.

This object contains the event handlers we talked about earlier (the ones you are spreading on your element) and it looks like this:

```js
{
  onMouseDown: start as MouseEventHandler<Target>,
  onMouseMove: handleMove as MouseEventHandler<Target>,
  onMouseUp: cancel as MouseEventHandler<Target>,
  onMouseLeave: cancel as MouseEventHandler<Target>,
  onTouchStart: start as TouchEventHandler<Target>,
  onTouchMove: handleMove as TouchEventHandler<Target>,
  onTouchEnd: cancel as TouchEventHandler<Target>,
}
```

But the problem is the fact that this `cancel` function is where `useLongPress.js` performs its logic and calls your onCancel method. This is also using a `useCallback`. So really the only place where you can bind your argument to your function is when you are calling the `useLongPress` hook.

In conclusion, as a dirty workaround you can try to write your code like this, but this is not necessarily the most performant or pretty looking code. So my suggestion to you is to change your library. (It's actually pretty simple, maybe even create your own hook?)

```js
{presets.map(preset => {
  const bind = useLongPress(longPress, { onCancel: shortPress.bind(null, preset) })
  return (
    <button 
      key={presets.indexOf(preset)} 
      onClick={() => start(preset)} 
      type="button" 
      {...bind}
    >
      <span>{preset.time}</span>
    </button>
})}
```

Comment: Come to think of it I think you have to more than what I just wrote there, since it occurred to me that you can not use React hooks this way: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions

Comment: Thanks for you reply. As you wrote, unfortunately I cannot use React hooks inside a return function. I'm just trying to detect `click` and `tap`, and `long click` and `long touch` events and that seems the most valid library I could find on npm. Any suggestions?